How to implement a custom composite meter and natively integrate it into Micrometer and Spring Boot Actuator?
I want to implement a new type of meter (HeartbeatMeter) to track the liveness of a heartbeat from an upstream source.
Interface would be very simple, something like:
    private interface HeartbeatMeter {
        void beat(Instant timestamp);
    }

Meter exposes 2 gauges:

{metric.name}.alive: 0 if the last heartbeat was recorded more than a timeout ago, 1 otherwise;
{metric.name}.timeout: a heartbeat timeout in seconds.

In order to natively integrate such meter in Micrometer I would like to follow the way other meters are being initialized:
    HeartbeatMeter myHeartbeat = HeartbeatMeter.builder("my.pipeline.heartbeat")
            .withTimeout(30),
            .tags(myTags)
            .register(meterRegistry);

    myHeartbeat.beat(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());

Registration should create a new meter if there is no meter with provided name and tags yet exists, and register it in meter registry. Otherwise it should return an existing meter from registry. And I don't know how to achieve that.
So far register method of the builder is following:
    public HeartbeatMeter register(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        var heartbeatMeter = new HeartbeatMeter(this.timeoutSeconds);

        Gauge.builder(String.format("%s.active", this.name), heartbeatMeter.activeSupplier())
                .tags(this.tags)
                .register(meterRegistry);
        Gauge.builder(String.format("%s.timeout", this.name), heartbeatMeter.timeoutSupplier())
                .tags(this.tags)
                .register(meterRegistry);

        return heartbeatMeter;
    }


While it works well if the meter is not yet registered, it is not gonna work if gauges are already present in a registry.
Is there a convenient way to implement a custom composite meter and integrate it into micrometer?
I'm interested about implementing custom composite meters in general, HeartbeatMeter was used as an example.

It seems this is not a custom composite meter but a component that simply registers two Gauges. You can implement a MeterBinder for this, Spring Boot will auto-register it for you if you create a bean of it.

Registration should create a new meter if there is no meter with provided name and tags yet exists, and register it in meter registry. Otherwise it should return an existing meter from registry. And I don't know how to achieve that.

Gauges are async so I'm not sure why you would need a Gauge instance since you don't interact with it, you interact with its backing object.

While it works well if the meter is not yet registered, it is not gonna work if gauges are already present in a registry.

I also don't get how you can get into a situation that Gauges are already present. You register your Gauges once and you don't need to re-register them or interact with them in any ways. Insyead you interact with their bacing object, please see the docs: https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/gauges.html
If you really want to check if a Meter (i.e.: Gauge) is registered, the MeterRegistry has a find and a get method to do this but (I cannot emphasize this enough) you don't need them to register your gauges, you might be doing something wrong.

I called it a composite meter because of the incapsulated logic that modify gauge bases on "beat" method and provides a new type of observability. In the end timer also just exposes few counters and gauges. I'm looking to extend registry to have interaction close to interaction provided for timer.
The "create or register" part is taken from "MeterRegistry.timer" javadoc and true for all other meters except gauge.
To simulate builders flow so far the only way I see is to store all heartbeat meters inside of a builder itself. Or is there a better way avaibale?

Yes, as I mentioned above: you can implement a MeterBinder for this. Register your Gauges in your bindTo method and update their backing object in another one.
